# Two-way binding in WPF: Why does it matter which property I specify the binding on when I bind two properties of the same control?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have 2 textboxes and I want the value of each textbox to affect its own font size.

```
<WrapPanel>
    <TextBox x:Name="text1" Text="15" FontSize="{Binding Text, ElementName=text1}"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="text2" Text="{Binding FontSize, ElementName=text2}" FontSize="15"/>
</WrapPanel>
```

In the example above, when the user changes the value of the first textbox to a different number, the font size changes; however, this does not happen for the second textbox. In the first textbox, I am specifying the binding in the value for the FontSize property, but in the second textbox, I am specifying the binding in the value of the Text property. Since these are two-way bindings, why aren't they behaving the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually what you wrote does work. By default, the TextBox's Text property is set to update from the binding source when the TextBox loses focus. So if you type in something into text2 (i.e. 48) you won't see it change until you focus on some other object (i.e. click back onto text1).

If you want to change this to match how text1 behaves do this:

```
<TextBox x:Name="text2" Text="{Binding FontSize, ElementName=text2, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" FontSize="15"/>
```